# FCITX pinyin input menu doesnt appear

Tags: xubuntu, services, input-method, chinese, fcitx

I ham running fcitx in 15.04 XFCE Ubuntu (XUbuntu) and my fcitx daemon is working fine for both Chewing and Google Pinyin input, however the menu with pinyin entries never shows up when I type. So for example, I can type some Pinyin, hit a number, and the text is input on the screen, however I have no idea which number corresponds to what entry since the menu doesn't appear. I toyed with some settings to no avail. Am I missing something?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possibly an [fcitx bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fcitx).

Answer (score 4):

This seems due to the problem of fcitx-ui-qimpanel package.
I had the same problem and found that the qt panel for fcitx did not work properly after the system started. 
After removing this package, everything works well.

Comment: I can confirm this for Xubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I endorse this solution on xfce with ubuntu 19.10. Nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

Just want to second user472967's answer.  I had the same type of problem when using Chewying input.  After removing `fcitx-ui-qimpanel` package, it works!  Please see the below screenshot for the symptom of this issue before and after.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution works, though one needs to perform a reboot after removing the fcitx-ui-qimpanel package for the UI to behave properly again.