# Ubuntu fcitx menu can't select

Tags: gnome, fcitx

I used Ubuntu, and then installed `GNOME Tweaks tool`. Because `IBus` is not very friendly to Chinese, I installed `fcitx`.

After installation, I found that some of the `fcitx` drop-down options in the top bar could not be selected, such as skin options. I also found that after selection, they appeared and then disappeared.

I don't know how to set it up now, not even the reason for the software. Who can help me? Thank you. 
This message is translated by translator. I hope you can understand the inaccuracy.

[image]
problem on the top right

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you use ?

Comment: Is this your question ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/668269/fcitx-pinyin-input-menu-doesnt-appear?rq=1

Comment: i am uninstall this packs ,and i reload fcitx and the iocs of fcitx on the top bar diaappear.i think ifix this problem. thank you

Comment: Have you fixed your issue or not ? if still have this issue , then Try to report this bug : https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug